# How to stop Web-Essentials from striping off the 'px' when auto-minimifying CSS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

The auto-minimifier always remove the 'px' when the unit is zero, so the minified file is smaller.

However, it also strips out the 'px' from the 'flex' shorthand property, and this causes a bug in Internet Explorer.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Consider upgrading to VS2017. (Fwiw, the Community Edition is free.)

Comment: I am bugging my boss to upgrade to at least vs2015 since last year...

Comment: If you are able to postprocess the minifier’s output, you could try to use a dummy unit like `flexpx` instead of `px` where the minifier removes `px`, and then replace `flexpx` back to `px`. If the minifier removes _any_ unit as long as the value is zero, then a dummy _function_ like `px()` (+ postprocessing for the purpose of replacing the function-wrapped value with the real value) could probably be used as a workaround.

Comment: I found out that simply using '0.1px' instead of '0px' works and doesn't generate too much hassle, but thank you.